# How to triggered different function when user drag into element area in swift for ios

Tags: ios, swift

I'm sure that answer is near.
I'm new in swift and want to create simple app for iOS.
I have created view and add different elements on this view. Also added pan recognized for this view. I want to do different actions when user drag his finger over different element. For example when finger entered in button area to write in console, when dragged into label area - change labels's text. Also With this type realized swipe method of input text from keyboard. It must do in one touch that's why I use pan recognizer. But when I run my app, I can get finger position, but don't know how triggered function when need.
Hope for yours help
Thanx

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var mainView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var gest: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer!
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.gest)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

}

@IBAction func drAG(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.location(in: self.view))
}
```

Comment: In order to get help you need to provide the code that reproduces the problem. Here is how to create a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have most everything you need. Now, just use the hitTest() method of **any** view's layer:

```
func moveEye(_ recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let p = recognizer.location(in: self)
    if btn.layer.hitTest(p) != nil {
        // finger panned over btn
    }
}
```

I use hitTest() alot in a few apps. But beware - I usually see it associated with the tap gesture. (I use the pan gesture to move a subview.) I do not know how things will behave if you have two overlapping subviews that the user pans over.

Comment: It's exactly what I looking for! Thanx a lot!